# how to get first child of a class's index using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have set of tr rows with a given class:

```
           <tr class="rowgroupA"><td>Test Data Logs</td></tr>
           <tr class="rowgroupA"><td>Test Data Logs</td></tr>
           <tr class="rowgroupA"><td>Test Data Logs</td></tr>
           <tr class="rowgroupA"><td>Test Data Logs</td></tr>
           <tr class="rowgroupB"><td>Test Data Logs</td></tr> // I need this index
           <tr class="rowgroupB"><td>Test Data Logs</td></tr>
           <tr class="rowgroupB"><td>Test Data Logs</td></tr>
           <tr class="rowgroupB"><td>Test Data Logs</td></tr>
```

To be more specific, how would I get the first-child of class name rowgroupB's index using jquery?

Comment: Could you be more clear on exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Isn't index of the first element `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are using that returns `-1`, you can use `index` method:

```
$('table tr.rowgroupB').first().index();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SUfG2/

Comment: You don't even need `first()` here actually, as `index()` without arguments only applies to the first element in the jQuery object.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, you are absolutely right, I just want it to be a little semantic.